# Azure Policy DeployIfNotExists : Retention days must be greater than X days for SQL server

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-policy

I am trying to develop an Azure Policy (json) ensuring that for a given SQL Server with Auditing enabled (no need to check that), retention days period has been set to a value greater than X (let's say 90 days in my case).

I tried to use `deployIfNotExists` effect, with an `existenceCondition` on `retentionDays` field (greater than 90). In the `deployment` part, I set the field to 365.

I assigned the policy to a resource group in which I have a SQL Server with Auditing and retention days equal to 20.

But still, the policy appears as 'Compliant' and retentionDays remains the same. Here is the code :

```
  "if": {
    "field": "type",
    "equals": "Microsoft.Sql/servers"
  },
  "then": {
    "effect": "deployIfNotExists",
    "details": {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditingSettings",
      "roleDefinitionIds": [
        "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/XXXXXXXX"
      ],
      "existenceCondition": {
        "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditingSettings/retentionDays",
        "greater": "90"
      },
      "deployment": {
        "properties": {
          "mode": "incremental",
          "template": {
            "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "parameters": {
              "resourceName": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "location": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "retentionDays": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            },
            "variables": {},
            "resources": [{
              "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/auditingSettings",
              "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
              "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceName'), '/Default')]",
              "location": "[parameters('location')]",
              "dependsOn": [],
              "properties": {
                "retentionDays": "[parameters('retentionDays')]"
              }
            }],
            "outputs": {}
          },
          "parameters": {
            "location": {
              "value": "[field('location')]"
            },
            "resourceName": {
              "value": "[field('name')]"
            },
            "retentionDays": {
              "value": "365"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I am wondering if I am using the right alias at the right place. Any clue ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my code that works!!!!

```
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "deploy-sql-db-backupshorttermretentionpolicies",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "All",
    "description": "Deploy If Not Exists backupshorttermretentionpolicies",
    "parameters": {
      "effect": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Effect",
          "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy."
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "DeployIfNotExists",
          "Disabled"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "DeployIfNotExists"
      },
      "retentionDays": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Retention Days",
          "description": "Set the number of Backup Retention Days."
        },
        "defaultValue": "35"
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "field": "type",
        "equals": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases"
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
        "details": {
          "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupShortTermRetentionPolicies",
          "name": "default",
          "roleDefinitionIds": [
            "/providers/microsoft.authorization/roleDefinitions/####
          ],
          "existenceCondition": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupShortTermRetentionPolicies/retentionDays",
            "equals": "[parameters('retentionDays')]"
          },
          "deployment": {
            "properties": {
              "mode": "incremental",
              "template": {
                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "parameters": {
                  "serverName": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "shortTermRetention": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                },
                "resources": [
                  {
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'),'/default')]",
                    "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/backupShortTermRetentionPolicies",
                    "apiVersion": "2017-10-01-preview",
                    "properties": {
                      "retentionDays": "[parameters('shortTermRetention')]"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              "parameters": {
                "serverName": {
                  "value": "[field('fullname')]"
                },
                "shortTermRetention": {
                  "value": "[parameters('retentionDays')]"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.